# How to convert list of lists into a Pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list as follows and need to covert it a pandas dataframe.

```
mylist = [[2000, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8], [2001, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9], [2002, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8], [2003, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8]]
columns = ['year', 'score_1', 'score_2', 'score_3', 'score_4', 'score_5']
```

I want the dataframe to be as follows.

```
    year score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 score_5
0    2000   0.5    0.3     0.8      0.9     0.8
1    2001   0.5    0.6     0.8      0.9     0.9
2    2002   0.5    0.3     0.8      0.8     0.8
3    2003   0.9    0.9     0.9      0.9     0.8
```

Currently, I am following the following code. But it needs to restructure my original 'mylist' data as 'year' and 'scores'.

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[scores],index=[year],columns=columns)
```

Therefore, I would like to know if there is any easy way of doing this in pandas.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: I think you need `pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=columns)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If need only columns pass `mylist`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist,columns=columns)
print (df)

   year  score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4  score_5
0  2000      0.5      0.3      0.8      0.9      0.8
1  2001      0.5      0.6      0.8      0.9      0.9
2  2002      0.5      0.3      0.8      0.8      0.8
3  2003      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.8
```

But if need index by years use dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({x[0]: x[1:] for x in mylist},columns=columns[1:], orient='index')
print (df)

      score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4  score_5
2000      0.5      0.3      0.8      0.9      0.8
2001      0.5      0.6      0.8      0.9      0.9
2002      0.5      0.3      0.8      0.8      0.8
2003      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.8
```

And if need set index names add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
d = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in mylist}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,columns=columns[1:], orient='index').rename_axis(columns[0])
print (df)

      score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4  score_5
year                                             
2000      0.5      0.3      0.8      0.9      0.8
2001      0.5      0.6      0.8      0.9      0.9
2002      0.5      0.3      0.8      0.8      0.8
2003      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.8
```

Comment: Thank you!! Your solution worked for me!!