# Cannot Convert list of list using pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

This is my Data from the api from the looks of it, it is a list of list.

```
with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
api_instance = MetricsApi(api_client)
response = api_instance.query_metrics(
    _from=int(yesterday_start_dt.timestamp()),
    to=int(yesterday_end_dt.timestamp()),
    query="default_zero(sum:trace.servlet.request.hits{env:prd-main,service:api}.as_rate())",
)

result = response['series'][0]['pointlist']
print(result)

[[1648339200000.0, 1105.8433333333332], [1648339500000.0, 1093.3266666666666], [1648339800000.0, 1076.92], [1648340100000.0, 1059.5133333333333], [1648340400000.0, 1053.8966666666668], [1648340700000.0, 1041.2166666666667], [1648341000000.0, 1055.0533333333333], [1648341300000.0, 1037.8933333333334], [1648341600000.0, 1015.4], [1648341900000.0, 1003.3233333333334], [1648342200000.0, 1017.02], [1648342500000.0, 1017.7766666666666], [1648342800000.0, 1011.0333333333333], [1648343100000.0, 993.9366666666666], [1648343400000.0, 973.9733333333334], [1648343700000.0, 967.8433333333334], [1648344000000.0, 933.2166666666667], [1648344300000.0, 945.0833333333334], [1648344600000.0, 905.2166666666667], [1648344900000.0, 923.9966666666667], [1648345200000.0, 925.4633333333334], [1648345500000.0, 915.5533333333333], [1648345800000.0, 918.8966666666666], [1648346100000.0, 883.6], [1648346400000.0, 908.9166666666666], [1648346700000.0, 856.7333333333333], [1648347000000.0, 873.01], [1648347300000.0, 833.99], [1648347600000.0, 846.5466666666666], [1648347900000.0, 820.7833333333333], [1648348200000.0, 821.4633333333334], [1648348500000.0, 812.8633333333333], [1648348800000.0, 817.78], [1648349100000.0, 821.91], [1648349400000.0, 791.17], [1648349700000.0, 780.3066666666666], [1648350000000.0, 803.4633333333334], [1648350300000.0, 781.9033333333333], [1648350600000.0, 759.4933333333333], [1648350900000.0, 746.11], [1648351200000.0, 731.3133333333334], [1648351500000.0, 724.0533333333333], [1648351800000.0, 710.56], [1648352100000.0, 722.87], [1648352400000.0, 677.5266666666666], [1648352700000.0, 681.7833333333333], [1648353000000.0, 679.9233333333333], [1648353300000.0, 650.6466666666666], [1648353600000.0, 663.78], [1648353900000.0, 650.8133333333334], [1648354200000.0, 645.9133333333333], [1648354500000.0, 642.4566666666667], [1648354800000.0, 627.93], [1648355100000.0, 616.65], [1648355400000.0, 609.94], [1648355700000.0, 602.0733333333334], [1648356000000.0, 581.6133333333333], [1648356300000.0, 592.48], [1648356600000.0, 593.4], [1648356900000.0, 582.2633333333333], [1648357200000.0, 598.3766666666667], [1648357500000.0, 589.99], [1648357800000.0, 577.7433333333333], [1648358100000.0, 570.1733333333333], [1648358400000.0, 592.58], [1648358700000.0, 578.2533333333333], [1648359000000.0, 586.8833333333333], [1648359300000.0, 590.4033333333333], [1648359600000.0, 601.49], [1648359900000.0, 594.8], [1648360200000.0, 609.01], [1648360500000.0, 620.08], [1648360800000.0, 642.6466666666666], [1648361100000.0, 635.93], [1648361400000.0, 638.42], [1648361700000.0, 645.2], [1648362000000.0, 650.42], [1648362300000.0, 667.88], [1648362600000.0, 689.3666666666667], [1648362900000.0, 694.4433333333334], [1648363200000.0, 690.3933333333333], [1648363500000.0, 710.55], [1648363800000.0, 706.3], [1648364100000.0, 729.5], [1648364400000.0, 771.36], [1648364700000.0, 754.03], [1648365000000.0, 771.4866666666667], [1648365300000.0, 767.52], [1648365600000.0, 779.4133333333333], [1648365900000.0, 800.4266666666666], [1648366200000.0, 788.41], [1648366500000.0, 806.8666666666667], [1648366800000.0, 805.7466666666667], [1648367100000.0, 815.2433333333333], [1648367400000.0, 828.0833333333334], [1648367700000.0, 817.1966666666667], [1648368000000.0, 879.4733333333334], [1648368300000.0, 840.7933333333333], [1648368600000.0, 846.4266666666666], [1648368900000.0, 848.1266666666667], [1648369200000.0, 836.9066666666666], [1648369500000.0, 845.4966666666667], [1648369800000.0, 863.5033333333333], [1648370100000.0, 867.1866666666666], [1648370400000.0, 866.74], [1648370700000.0, 863.8066666666666], [1648371000000.0, 882.38], [1648371300000.0, 876.0233333333333], [1648371600000.0, 905.3366666666667], [1648371900000.0, 879.8066666666666], [1648372200000.0, 878.37], [1648372500000.0, 876.9333333333333], [1648372800000.0, 868.1533333333333], [1648373100000.0, 882.12], [1648373400000.0, 896.9233333333333], [1648373700000.0, 872.84], [1648374000000.0, 880.71], [1648374300000.0, 894.8066666666666], [1648374600000.0, 873.7266666666667], [1648374900000.0, 891.0033333333333], [1648375200000.0, 927.2433333333333], [1648375500000.0, 905.52], [1648375800000.0, 895.0233333333333], [1648376100000.0, 895.86], [1648376400000.0, 899.3133333333334], [1648376700000.0, 920.22], [1648377000000.0, 937.68], [1648377300000.0, 916.46], [1648377600000.0, 926.6833333333333], [1648377900000.0, 936.4366666666666], [1648378200000.0, 947.6133333333333], [1648378500000.0, 957.7133333333334], [1648378800000.0, 989.1133333333333], [1648379100000.0, 959.0766666666667], [1648379400000.0, 963.5133333333333], [1648379700000.0, 978.3466666666667], [1648380000000.0, 1017.78], [1648380300000.0, 989.7566666666667], [1648380600000.0, 1023.4633333333334], [1648380900000.0, 1033.7166666666667], [1648381200000.0, 1025.1933333333334], [1648381500000.0, 1045.8633333333332], [1648381800000.0, 1063.6133333333332], [1648382100000.0, 1078.45], [1648382400000.0, 1116.3866666666668], [1648382700000.0, 1098.9766666666667], [1648383000000.0, 1101.29], [1648383300000.0, 1127.6], [1648383600000.0, 1102.5233333333333], [1648383900000.0, 1140.84], [1648384200000.0, 1169.23], [1648384500000.0, 1158.6], [1648384800000.0, 1180.01], [1648385100000.0, 1190.43], [1648385400000.0, 1207.3733333333332], [1648385700000.0, 1212.7666666666667], [1648386000000.0, 1244.17], [1648386300000.0, 1245.3166666666666], [1648386600000.0, 1240.69], [1648386900000.0, 1270.33], [1648387200000.0, 1277.8033333333333], [1648387500000.0, 1270.5966666666666], [1648387800000.0, 1304.4266666666667], [1648388100000.0, 1295.6933333333334], [1648388400000.0, 1322.3066666666666], [1648388700000.0, 1351.41], [1648389000000.0, 1339.9566666666667], [1648389300000.0, 1353.2966666666666], [1648389600000.0, 1398.45], [1648389900000.0, 1378.21], [1648390200000.0, 1361.0933333333332], [1648390500000.0, 1404.0833333333333], [1648390800000.0, 1394.6466666666668], [1648391100000.0, 1391.1366666666668], [1648391400000.0, 1450.0], [1648391700000.0, 1438.97], [1648392000000.0, 1411.83], [1648392300000.0, 1432.8233333333333], [1648392600000.0, 1473.3966666666668], [1648392900000.0, 1491.0166666666667], [1648393200000.0, 1509.8766666666668], [1648393500000.0, 1488.6566666666668], [1648393800000.0, 1488.4933333333333], [1648394100000.0, 1511.4466666666667], [1648394400000.0, 1508.3566666666666], [1648394700000.0, 1507.8966666666668], [1648395000000.0, 1515.8633333333332], [1648395300000.0, 1517.3], [1648395600000.0, 1528.81], [1648395900000.0, 1546.1266666666668], [1648396200000.0, 1554.57], [1648396500000.0, 1584.0333333333333], [1648396800000.0, 1584.45], [1648397100000.0, 1590.4633333333334], [1648397400000.0, 1580.0066666666667], [1648397700000.0, 1596.3833333333334], [1648398000000.0, 1571.96], [1648398300000.0, 1583.8233333333333], [1648398600000.0, 1618.7033333333334], [1648398900000.0, 1588.12], [1648399200000.0, 1599.56], [1648399500000.0, 1604.1833333333334], [1648399800000.0, 1621.5666666666666], [1648400100000.0, 1598.98], [1648400400000.0, 1627.02], [1648400700000.0, 1612.7833333333333], [1648401000000.0, 1612.2433333333333], [1648401300000.0, 1572.89], [1648401600000.0, 1601.8933333333334], [1648401900000.0, 1612.5366666666666], [1648402200000.0, 1608.7266666666667], [1648402500000.0, 1594.4366666666667], [1648402800000.0, 1614.3366666666666], [1648403100000.0, 1649.0733333333333], [1648403400000.0, 1627.12], [1648403700000.0, 1644.9633333333334], [1648404000000.0, 1653.9033333333334], [1648404300000.0, 1636.6966666666667], [1648404600000.0, 1639.5733333333333], [1648404900000.0, 1627.3866666666668], [1648405200000.0, 1626.3733333333332], [1648405500000.0, 1616.7966666666666], [1648405800000.0, 1667.2933333333333], [1648406100000.0, 1637.0733333333333], [1648406400000.0, 1654.6366666666668], [1648406700000.0, 1673.9566666666667], [1648407000000.0, 1658.4466666666667], [1648407300000.0, 1650.6766666666667], [1648407600000.0, 1662.1933333333334], [1648407900000.0, 1686.9733333333334], [1648408200000.0, 1623.0433333333333], [1648408500000.0, 1630.2866666666666], [1648408800000.0, 1599.0466666666666], [1648409100000.0, 1624.8033333333333], [1648409400000.0, 1606.0333333333333], [1648409700000.0, 1594.15], [1648410000000.0, 1557.1333333333334], [1648410300000.0, 1630.6133333333332], [1648410600000.0, 1591.93], [1648410900000.0, 1579.5733333333333], [1648411200000.0, 1585.1466666666668], [1648411500000.0, 1565.6166666666666], [1648411800000.0, 1566.3366666666666], [1648412100000.0, 1544.1866666666667], [1648412400000.0, 1511.8166666666666], [1648412700000.0, 1525.2333333333333], [1648413000000.0, 1505.57], [1648413300000.0, 1462.9033333333334], [1648413600000.0, 1478.0733333333333], [1648413900000.0, 1460.76], [1648414200000.0, 1504.59], [1648414500000.0, 1460.3366666666666], [1648414800000.0, 1445.9366666666667], [1648415100000.0, 1410.0033333333333], [1648415400000.0, 1412.8466666666666], [1648415700000.0, 1364.8933333333334], [1648416000000.0, 1348.4], [1648416300000.0, 1338.3333333333333], [1648416600000.0, 1326.8633333333332], [1648416900000.0, 1276.24], [1648417200000.0, 1310.0333333333333], [1648417500000.0, 1285.63], [1648417800000.0, 1244.14], [1648418100000.0, 1258.38], [1648418400000.0, 1218.37], [1648418700000.0, 1182.0266666666666], [1648419000000.0, 1196.8133333333333], [1648419300000.0, 1144.54], [1648419600000.0, 1165.62], [1648419900000.0, 1122.0166666666667], [1648420200000.0, 1112.6766666666667], [1648420500000.0, 1102.6], [1648420800000.0, 1095.6966666666667], [1648421100000.0, 1056.63], [1648421400000.0, 1074.5066666666667], [1648421700000.0, 1047.5933333333332], [1648422000000.0, 1057.2633333333333], [1648422300000.0, 1043.99], [1648422600000.0, 1003.4033333333333], [1648422900000.0, 1022.2633333333333], [1648423200000.0, 1016.59], [1648423500000.0, 997.4466666666667], [1648423800000.0, 988.7666666666667], [1648424100000.0, 966.1666666666666], [1648424400000.0, 991.21], [1648424700000.0, 977.6633333333333], [1648425000000.0, 959.64], [1648425300000.0, 961.6989966555184]]
```

But when i try to convert into pandas it convert but the result is what i expected, i expected that the dataframe will make two columns.

```
with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
api_instance = MetricsApi(api_client)
response = api_instance.query_metrics(
    _from=int(yesterday_start_dt.timestamp()),
    to=int(yesterday_end_dt.timestamp()),
    query="default_zero(sum:trace.servlet.request.hits{env:prd-main,service:api}.as_rate())",
)

result = response['series'][0]['pointlist']
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)



                                        0
0    [1648339200000.0, 1105.8433333333332]
1    [1648339500000.0, 1093.3266666666666]
2               [1648339800000.0, 1076.92]
3    [1648340100000.0, 1059.5133333333333]
4    [1648340400000.0, 1053.8966666666668]
..                                     ...
283   [1648424100000.0, 966.1666666666666]
284              [1648424400000.0, 991.21]
285   [1648424700000.0, 977.6633333333333]
286              [1648425000000.0, 959.64]
287   [1648425300000.0, 961.6989966555184]

[288 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: It looks like `result` is a list of strings of the form `[1648339200000.0, 1105.8433333333332]`. You should be able to read them with `pd.DataFrame(json.loads(r) for r in result)`

Comment: @Nick i tried you code but i getting new error:

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Point`

Comment: @Nick `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Point`

Comment: Ah, so the values are `Point`, then perhaps `pd.DataFrame([p.x, p.y] for p in result)`?

Comment: @Nick it says the point has no attribute x: `ApiAttributeError: Point has no attribute 'x' at ['['received_data', 'series', 0, 'pointlist', 0]']['x']`

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas... you must have a different `Point` object...

Comment: I believe this post gives you the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644342/how-to-convert-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comment referring to another answer, here how you may do it.

```
columns = ['point 1', 'point 2']
result = response['series'][0]['pointlist']
df = pd.DataFrame(result,columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first elements of sublists to be in one column, I suggest you create an intermediate np.array and then reshape it into the needed output.

```
array_results=np.array(results)
df=pd.DataFrame(array_results.reshape(2, len(results)))
```

following few samples of 'results', here are my outputs
[image]